# I cannot get just the selected values from dropdownlists in my view back in my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I hava a view where I have a list of links, being each link a region where the companies has offices.

Everytime I select a region, I get a list of processes. For every process, I get a dropdowlist  from where to choose a owner of the process and a list of checkboxs of tests to choose.

In my controller, I get string[] OwnerId as the values selected in the dropdowlists. 
The thing is, I get all values from all dropdowlists, not just those that were selected. How can I get just the ones I selected??

This is my view

```
@using CTTModel
@using TestingTool.ViewModels
@model TestRunModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>
    Create</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Regions</legend>
        @foreach (Region region in Model.Regions)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(@region.Name, "Create", new { id = region.Id })<br />
        }

        <div class="editor-field">
            @foreach (ProcessModel process in Model.Processes)
            {
                <h1>@process.Name</h1>

                **List<User> users = ViewBag.Users;

                <select id="OwnerId" name="OwnerId" >

                    @foreach (User user in users)
                    {
                        <option value="@user.Id">@user.Name</option>
                    }

                </select>**  

                <table>
                    <tr>
                          @{
                    int cnt = 0;

                    foreach (TestModel testModel in process.Tests)
                    {
                        if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                        {
                                      @:  </tr> <tr> 
                                  }
                                  @: <td> 
                                  <input type="checkbox" 
                                         name="selectedTests" 
                                         value="@testModel.Id/@testModel.ProcessId/@testModel.RegionId" 
                                       @(Html.Raw(testModel.Active ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                  @testModel.Name @::  @testModel.Description
                                  @:</td>
                              }
                              @: </tr>
                          }
                </table>
            }
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test Screen</legend>
    </fieldset>   
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

And this is my controller. The Create Post does nothing yet, I'm trying to get the right values first.

```
//
        // GET: /TestPreparation/Create

        public ActionResult Create(int id = 1)
        {
            TestRunModel testRunModel = new TestRunModel();

            foreach (Region region in _db.Regions)
            {
                testRunModel.Regions.Add(region);
            }

            TestRun testRun = _db.TestRuns.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First();

            foreach (TestRunProcessRegion region in testRun.GetProcessesForRegion(_db.Regions.Single(i => i.Id == id)))
            {
                ProcessModel process = new ProcessModel
                    {
                        Code        = region.ProcessRegion.Process.Code,
                        Description = region.ProcessRegion.Process.Description,
                        Name        = region.ProcessRegion.Process.Name,
                        Process     = region.ProcessRegion.Process.Id
                    };

                foreach (SubProcess subProcess in region.ProcessRegion.Process.SubProcesses)
                {
                    foreach (Risk risk in subProcess.Risks)
                    {
                        foreach (Test test in risk.Tests)
                        {
                            TestModel testModel = new TestModel
                                {
                                    Id = test.Id,
                                    Name = test.Name,
                                    Description = test.Description,
                                    ProcessId = region.ProcessRegion.Process.Id,
                                    RegionId = region.ProcessRegion.Id
                                };

                            process.Tests.Add(testModel);
                        }
                    }
                }

                testRunModel.Processes.Add(process);
            }


            var users = new List<User>();
            foreach (User user in _db.Users)
            {
                users.Add(new User
                {
                    Id = user.Id,
                    Name = user.Name,
                });
            }

            ViewBag.Users = users;

            return View(testRunModel);
        } 

        //
        // POST: /TestPreparation/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string[] OwnerId, string[] selectedTests, string[] processes)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //_db.TestRunStatus.Add(testrunstatus);
                //_db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting any data back is because the method signature of your Post Action needs to be

```
public ActionResult Create(string OwnerId ...) //preferably int depending on what OwnerId is
```

This is because you only select one item out of the drop down box. So if you use this signature as opposed to string[], the Model binder will pass the selected value back to your action.

Having said this, it is better practice and the "MVC Way" to use,

`Html.DropDownFor(x => x.UserID)` it really makes things easier :)

This applies to all html input controls:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

***UPDATE***

I think the best thing to do would be to add an OwnerID to the `ProccessModel` class. 
Becuase `ProccessModel` looks to be `IEnumberable<ProccessModel> Processes` contained in the ViewModel you can get the Model to Bind in the following way using the defult MVC model binder.

Phil Haack has bloged about binding to lists here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Adapting from Phil's post I think you will have to do something like this:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Processes.Count; i++) { %>

  <%: Html.SelectListFor(model => model.Processes[i].OwnerID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Users) %> 
<% } %>
```

Change the ViewBag.User to:

```
 var users = _db.Users.Select(x => new SelectListItem(){
                                   text = x.Name, 
                                   value = x.Value
                              });
```

Modify the Post Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TestRunModel model)
{
    foreach(var process in model.Porcesses)
   {
      process.OwnerID // This should be a user selected value
   }
   // code removed for brevity 
}
```

I could help with getting the TestModel values if you like but I need to do some work now ;)

Comment: That would be the case if I had one Dropdowlist, I have a @Foreach that creates several and I want to receive only those selected. Could be all, just one, two, etc.